# Callback uri not opening in google api installed application

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-api-java-client

I am writing a small desktop application in java with the google fusion tables java client using oauth2. I am able to get the browser to open so the user can log in to his/her google account, but after logging in the application crashes giving me this exception:

```
Please open the following address in your browser:
  https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=611708255166-npbqbne71spdn8fa1tfsegbl2msi8lsk.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://localhost:63909/Callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables
Attempting to open that address in the default browser now...
2013-08-21 11:27:28.076:WARN::/Callback?code=4/V8EpwmnrtF48VjXerABWDPZNyllS.ov1iLPSii_IVshQV0ieZDAps5vxCgQI
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer()V
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver$CallbackHandler.handle(LocalServerReceiver.java:220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

So it seems like the callback uri is not working. I do not want my call back uri to point to any website since this is a desktop application, but I want to somehow go back to my application to let the user know that the call to fusion tables has finished.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of stating the obvious, the error is "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.flushBuffer"

If I look at the LocalServerReceiver.java:220 class at https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/google-oauth-client-jetty/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/extensions/jetty/auth/oauth2/LocalServerReceiver.java?r=2c0510b314d24701810aa277f5d803a4368b2e20

line 220 is blank.

So I would double check your library versions.

Also check your classpath to see where javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse is being found.